# my .htaccess file not suport in godady account

Tags: php, .htaccess

all i have setup new webhos http://www.godaddy.com/ and i uploaded my website to this `godaday` hosting.  now problem is that my `.htaccess` is not working.

just 404 error page is working on `.htaccess`

my .htacces file code is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.)web(.).html /webdetail.php?t=$1&webid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([^/\.]+)/?$ catagory.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^c/(.)/(.) /catagory.php?page=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^c-p/(.) /catagory.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^c/ catagory.php
RewriteRule ^statep/(.)/(.)/(.) /state.php?state=$1&cat=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^statep/(.)/(.) /state.php?state=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^state/(.)/(.) /state.php?state=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^state/(.) /state.php?state=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^statep /state.php
RewriteRule ^cityp/(.)/(.)/(.) /city.php?city=$1&cat=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^cityp/(.)/(.) /city.php?city=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^city/(.)/(.) /city.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^city/(.) /city.php?city=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cityp /city.php
RewriteRule ^recentvisit/(.) /recentvisit.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^mostvisited/(.) /mostvisited.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^allcategorys/(.) /allcategorys.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^recentvisit recentvisit.php
RewriteRule ^mostvisited mostvisited.php
RewriteRule ^allcategorys allcategorys.php
RewriteRule ^sms/(.) /sms.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webs/(.)/(.) /webdetail.php?webid=$1&t=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^mailwebs/(.)/(.) /mailtocompany.php?webid=$1&t=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^contactus contactus.php
RewriteRule ^(.)state(.)/(.) /state.php?state=$1&cat=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)state/(.) /state.php?state=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-state(.).html /state.php?state=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)state.html /state.php?state=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-city(.)/(.) /city.php?city=$1&cat=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)city/(.) /city.php?city=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-city(.).html /city.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-city.html /city.php?city=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-tag/(.) /catagory.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.)-tag.html /catagory.php?cat=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/error.php
```

i am using php

Comment: Have you already asked godaddy support?

Comment: no, i dont ask @ `godaddy support` and how to ask ?

Comment: support.godaddy.com/?ci=55601 Try this link, you should be able to log in an create a support ticket.

Comment: its not error message but all url go to `http://www.mydomain.com/error.php` link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess to help setup the correct defaults:

```
     RewriteBase / 
     ErrorDocument 404 default
     Options +FollowSymLinks
```